# how to combine 2 object in json array and give comma?

Tags: javascript, html

hi i need help to write a format code.
i write javascript code to parse json and use the data, the json file contain latitude and longtitude data :

```
const api_url = 'json.php'
async function getjsonlatest() {
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    const data = await response.json();
```

i can grab data from array [0]

```
const api_url = 'json.php'
async function getjsonlatest() {
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    const data = await response.json();
    const latitude = (data[0].latitude)
    const longitude = (data[0].longtitude)
    console.log(latitude)
    console.log(longitude)
```

the console.log result is (line 1) -7.247100
(line 2) 112.775340

i need to format like this [latitude,longitude] to fill this code :

```
marker.setLatLng([latitude, longtitude]);
```

how can achieve that?

Comment: So you need to pass an array to `marker.setLatLng()`?  Have you tried what you have above?  That should work.

Comment: Can you explain what the issue is with passing `latitude` and `longitude` to `setLatLng` in the way you've described...? Why do you care how it's formatted in your console, exactly?

Comment: Unclear what your question is. Does the above not work? What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to worry about the comma.

```
marker.setLatLng([latitude, longtitude]);
```

this code is already functional and will call setLatLng() with an array arg containing latitude and longitude

Comment: i already try your advice Mr. and it works, thankyou so much for your help Mr. :-)

Comment: No problem, please mark the answer as correct if it helped you :)